# SQL Error 1064, 42000 You have an error in your SQL syntax but unable to spot the problem

Tags: php, sql

SOLVED: One argument wasn't passed to the function.

---

I am trying to update a record in the database using PDO in PHP. 
When executing the query I receive an error 1604.

[42000,1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 WHERE id = 175' at line 1"]

The query gets executed from a new method in a Class for a API

```
public function updateRaceTeamOrder($forRace, $position){

    $race_set ="";

    if ($forRace=="GS") {
        $race_set = "raceGS_position";
    }
    if ($forRace=="SB") {
        $race_set = "raceSB_position";
    }
    if ($forRace=="XC") {
        $race_set = "raceXC_position";
    }

    $query = "UPDATE " . $this->table_name . "SET {$race_set}=:raceTeamPosition WHERE id = :id";

     $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize


    $this->id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));
    $position=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($position));

    if (!is_int($this->id)) {
        $this->id = intval($this->id);
    }

    if (!is_int($position)) {
        $position = intval($position);
    }

    $stmt->bindParam(':raceTeamPosition', $position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // execute the query
    if($stmt->execute()){ 
        return true;
    }

    return $stmt->errorInfo();
```

Comment: Try echoing out your query to see what it contains.

Comment: The answer should be obvious, with the lack of spaces around keywords.

Comment: You are missing a space before `SET`.

Comment: true with the missing space but didn't solve the porblem same result

Comment: What does your query show when you echo it?

Comment: echo $query => UPDATE guests SET =:raceTeamPosition WHERE id = :id

Comment: found the Problem - you should pass all Agrs to the function in order to get the correct output

Answer (score 0):

```
$race_set = "default_race_set";     
if ($forRace=="GS") {
        $race_set = "raceGS_position";
    }
    if ($forRace=="SB") {
        $race_set = "raceSB_position";
    }
    if ($forRace=="XC") {
        $race_set = "raceXC_position";
    }
```

or

```
if ($forRace=="GS") {
    $race_set = "raceGS_position";
}elseif ($forRace=="SB") {
    $race_set = "raceSB_position";
}elseif ($forRace=="XC") {
     $race_set = "raceXC_position";
}else{
     die("err");
}
```